# jQuery/Javascript slideshow not changing image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

this can be found on http://adamginther.com, when the Canucks icon is clicked. The Canucks icon is the third icon underneath "information architecture and usability.

I am trying to create a jQuery slideshow and used a template to create it and I have no idea why it isn't working. There is a div that contains the three images for the slideshow, and jQuery to check if which image is active and adjust the z-index. I wish I could be more descriptive but I'm not a master of jQuery and JS and found this template online.

HTML

```
    <p>
            <button class="closeButton">X</button>
        <br>
        <br><class id="blueText">You are viewing: Canucks Usability Tests</class><br>Role: Usability Testing<br><br>The Vancouver Canucks is one of Canada's biggest sports teams, with a very strong and avid community. A lot of their community use their website to interact with each other about recent trades, rumours, and debates. 
        <br>
        <br>
        I was tasked with testing the usablity of Canucks.NHL.com's community features and social features. This involved in analyzing Canucks' target user and thinking of the potential downfalls the user may have while navigating the website and recording a test participant doing so. These tests ended up being successful in pointing out the uncovered flaws.
    </p>
        <div id="slideshow">
        <img src="images/work/canucks1.png" alt="Canucks Image 1" class="active">
        <img src="images/work/canucks2.png" alt="Canucks Image 2">
        <img src="images/work/canucks3.png" alt="Canucks Image 3">
    </div>
```

jQuery/Javascript

```
function slideSwitch() {
    var $active = $('#slideshow IMG.active');

    if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow IMG:last');

    // use this to pull the images in the order they appear in the markup
    var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
        : $('#slideshow IMG:first');

    $active.addClass('last-active');

    $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
        .addClass('active')
        .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
            $active.removeClass('active last-active');
        });
}

$(function() {
    setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 5000 );
});
```

Comment: can you show jsfiddle or jsbin?

Comment: Seems like that's been put together with some copy/paste. By the way, check in console, there's a few errors there.

Comment: there is an error but that is for an application I run locally, when the website is complete the script is going to be removed. It was made with some copy and paste and some adjustments.

Comment: I've never used JS Fiddle extensively but this is what I have. I can't figure out how to display images. this is the JS Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/gintherthegreat/d7dC3/1/

Answer (score 0):

as per JSFiddle provided
Here is **[updated solution On JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d7dC3/9/)**

[**DEMO on JSBIN**](http://jsbin.com/oxamaj/2)

You were checking length on `'.active elements'` which will be always 1 (as there will be 1 active element at any given point)...
Also Same way `$active.next()` there will no such element as `length of $active is 1`

BELOW is updated code.. Let me know if you need any clarification on it.

```
function slideSwitch() {
    var imgs=$("#slideshow img");
    var $active = imgs.filter('.active');

    if ( $active.length == 0 ){
        $active = imgs.last();
    }
    // use this to pull the images in the order they appear in the markup
    var activeIndex=imgs.index($active);
    var $next = (activeIndex ===( imgs.length-1)) ?imgs.first(): imgs.eq(activeIndex+1); // THis line changed...

    $active.addClass('last-active');

    $next.css({opacity: '0.0'})
    .addClass('active')
    .animate({opacity: '1.0'}, 1000, function() {
            $active.removeClass('active last-active');
        });
}

$(function() {
       setInterval( slideSwitch, 5000 );// This line changed
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have here for you a tutorial on how to create a jQuery slider from scratch. The steps are simple and i believe its useful for you question.

You just need to prepare the HTML, CSS and the javaScript code.

`$(document).ready( function($){var slider = $('.slider').find('ul'); })`

and your all done. sorry for the short code i displayed. I don't know how to format the code using this text editor. just visit the link for more information. http://nextopics.com/creating-jquery-slider-from-scratch/ hope this helps.